# Wake On Lan just doesn't want to work

Tags: windows, bios, lan, wake-on-lan

It just doesn't want to work, believe me I've tried everything. Windows says driver is up to date. In advanced everything about WoL is enabled. In Bios it's enabled. The problem is after shut down the NIC is turned off, even though the check box in properties of driver in power management is unchecked.
Please help!

DETAILS:

MB: AsRock 970 Extreme3
NIC: Integrated

Comment: Is your BIOS up to date? Is it BIOS or UEFI? Is that NIC on board or external? Maybe you could post model of your MB, NIC...

Comment: its uefi and the nic internal. i think its asrock 970 extreme x or something like that

Comment: are you in the same local network? what client are you using?

Comment: of course, what do you mean by client?

Comment: Please [update your post](http://superuser.com/posts/643267/edit) with accurate answer. Replying with "or something like that" isn't really on as we need to know facts, not guesses.

Comment: updated the post